# where can i find all ioctl for frame buffer and their functions?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was studying about frame buffer ioctls but it was incomplete documentation and it referred me linux/fb.h file for more ioctls but from the source code i couldn't figure out the function of ioctls are the are not well commented.so how can i understand ioctls function from source code or is there good documents available for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the IOCTL's listed at [1], also there might be some driver specific ioctls as well, for which you need to choose a particular driver and go through the driver code.

[1] https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/fb.h